# How to refresh screen so that closed forms actually disappear

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have multiple forms that popup during an intensive operation. For example, when a form popups asking user for something, and the user clicks OK, the form's graphics stay on the main screen, even though it is closed. How can I make it so that these graphics disappear completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend performing the heavy work in the background (using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) for instance), so that the GUI thread is not blocked. That way, the forms will be able to peform screen updates while the work is going on.

Comment: I moved the operations to a thread and now the GUI refreshes perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like perhaps you are doing intensive processing on your main thread, which is the thread that processes events like painting windows.  Instead you should spawn a separate thread for doing your computations/tasks so that your main thread can continue.

Alternatively you can call DoEvents() periodically while doing your processing to allow the form to refresh, but using DoEvents is kind of a cludge in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Refresh() method on the main screen form, which will force a graphics repaint.